# Quickblox iOS Crashes at unspecific time

Tags: ios, xmpp, quickblox, xmppframework

I've nearly finished developing an application using Quickblox for chat. Everything seems to be ok then the app will randomly crash with the below appearing.

It seems to happen at the point where the app receives/sends presence. Any suggestions?

[image: Quickblox Error]
[image: Quickblox Error]

*Update*

I've been testing on two devices and I haven't seen the crash again so it could be specific to the simulator.

*Update 2*

It occurred on the iphone for first time running ios 8.1.2

*Update 3*

Definitely a problem. Any ideas? Happening frequently.

[image: Quickblox Error]

Comment: Please tell me which version SDK you use and where you have downloaded it.

I've tried to reproduce this bug on a simulator & device and I can see that latest version of SDK does not have this bug.

Comment: This is the entry in my podfile - pod 'QuickBlox'

Comment: Please wait for the Monday and I will look deeply into your problem. I think I will find a solution. Till the Monday please try not to use chatDidReceiveContactItemActivity in your code

Comment: ok thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Hi SevenDays - I was initiating my chat service twice in error -  [QBChat instance].delegate = self was getting called twice. I have not seen the issue since I resolved this. I will test more and see if it comes up again. Thanks.

Comment: Please try a framework by the link below and let me know if the issue still persists or not. It's a temporary solution, so with next release please use cocoa pods.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/81t1yuitg8nomll/Quickblox.framework.zip